# JPA 1 relationship table, 2 independant classes using a common class with @OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Basically I would like to impement Addresses on Companies and Individuals. Addresses are separate entities.

a Company can have an AddressContext which uses the same Address entity as an Indivuduals AddressContext

AddressContext gives the address meaning in relation to the Individual, eg "My Home Address"

java classes:

```
public class Address {
}

public class AddressContext {
    private Address address;
    private String name;
}

public class Individual {
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private Set<AddressContext> addresseContexts;
}

public class Company {
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private Set<AddressContext> addresseContexts;
}
```

required database address_context database table

```
CREATE TABLE `address_Context` (
   `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   'address_id bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
   'RELATED_ITEM_ID bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   'RELATED_ITEM_TYPE varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   'NAME' varchar(5) 
);
```

basically having the following

```
1, 1, 1, Individual, 'John's House';
2, 2, 1, Company, 'Depoy';
```

What is actually happening is that separate tables are being created

```
companies_address_contexts
individuals_address_contexts
```

Is the above possible? I dont want to subclass AddressContext either

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to restrict a particular address to an entity type (Individual/Company). Think about  the (edge) case where a self-employed individual uses their home address *as* their company address. Or the case where a multi-tenant unit gets converted into an office complex. You get the gist - addresses should be completely separate entities that other entities in your system then refer to via *association tables*.

In your case, the association tables got generated anyway, you just need some minor refactoring to use (a form of) them, in your code. Something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Address {
    // address fields etc
}

@Entity
public class Individual {
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinTable(name = "individual_addresses", 
       joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "individual_id", unique = true) }, 
       inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "address_id") })
   private Set<Address> addresses;
}

@Entity
public class Company {
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinTable(name = "company_addresses", 
       joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", unique = true) }, 
       inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "address_id") })
   private Set<Address> addresses;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have given a more complete example. My addresses are in fact unique, and associated with companies/individuals via AddressContext. I have updated my initial post